# Работа с функцией с бесконечным количеством аргументов - func(...)

Tags: c++, функции

Подскажите, как работать с таким троеточием в скобках. Мне нужна функция, которая суммирует неопределенное количество целых чисел. Можно примером или ссылкой на нормальный ресурс.

----ДОПОЛНЕНО ПОСЛЕ 2-х КОММЕНТАРИЕВ --------

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int a, ...){
int * p = &a;

while (*p){
    cout << *p << endl;
    p++;
}
}

int main(){
f(1, 3, 56, 4);

return 0;
}
```

---------------вывод-------------------------------------

```
1
3
56
4
22997204
30403626
2147303424
-858993460
-858993460
1245112
4305311
1
3430632
3421160
-1011716776
22997204
30403626
2147303424
-1302397296
```

Не пойму, откуда мусор берётся?

Comment: Такая штука называется **variadic function** (чаще всего употребляется термин **varargs**). [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804) описывается несколько подходов, самый прямолинейный - сишный, с++-way - это, насколько понимаю, через template.

Ну и как там ниже написано - вполне корректным будет оформить это некоторое количество чисел в виде вектора.

Comment: [Вот][1], например
____

@perfect, у меня Ваш пример отработал правильно (запускал в VS 2013). Какой компилятор используете?

  [1]: http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/418970.1

Comment: Вам просто повезло. Дело в том, что аргументы в данном случае будут расположены в стеке. Но в стеке много чего ещё другого расположено (к примеру, адрес возврата из функции). Код в вопросе наивно надеется, что  после последнего аргумента в стеке будет 0. Да, такое может быть, но никто этого не гарантирует.

Но куда веселее будет, если список аргументов начнется с 0. В этом случае функция решит, что там совсем ничего нет.

Comment: @Donil vs 2010 под windows xp. @KoVadim правы.

Answer (score 2):

О мусоре я уже рассказал в комментарии - во время выполнения нет официальных способов узнать кол-во аргументов в стеке. Но если использовать новый стандарт (ну, какой он новый, ему уже несколько лет и поддерживается всеми адекватными компиляторами) и чуточку видоизменить синтаксис, то можно написать так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int summ(std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int x: list) {
        s += x;
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int a = summ({1,2,3,4});
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(компилировать нужно с ключом `-std=c++0x`)

Дополнительные фигурные скобки не так страшны, но плюсов приносят много. Можно даже такое написать `func({1,2,3,4},{5,8,9}, "test");` - сразу понятно, что функция будет принимать два списка и строку (заголовок функции будет такой `void func(std::initializer_list<int> list1, std::initializer_list<int> list2, std::string s);`.

Comment: Интересный способ, спасибо.